`output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'>
error log
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=num_train_examples//batch_size, epochs=500, callbacks=callbacks,\
      2                    validation_data=eval_generator, validation_steps=num_eval_examples//batch_size, verbose=1)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my-conda-env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my-conda-env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py:124, in _from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args, output_signature, name)
    122   for spec in nest.flatten(output_signature):
    123     if not isinstance(spec, type_spec.TypeSpec):
--> 124       raise TypeError(f"`output_signature` must contain objects that are "
    125                       f"subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found {type(spec)} "
    126                       f"which is not.")
    127 else:
    128   if output_types is None:

TypeError: `output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'> which is not.

error occurring code
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=num_train_examples//batch_size, epochs=500, callbacks=callbacks,\
                   validation_data=eval_generator, validation_steps=num_eval_examples//batch_size, verbose=1)

Can someone help me with this error? Not able to train my model because of this.
I tried to check the generator code but couldn't find any relevant leads.
Edit: The airsim notebook i am using to train the model: https://github.com/microsoft/AutonomousDrivingCookbook/blob/master/AirSimE2EDeepLearning/TrainModel.ipynb
The code for the DriveDataGenerator class is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/AutonomousDrivingCookbook/blob/master/AirSimE2EDeepLearning/Generator.py

You need to show us the code that defines all the parameters in the call to model.fit, to find out which parameter it is complaining about.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

@OldBoy hey i have edited the code to add the notebook i am using. I am new here so idk if i can post the whole notebook or not because i thought it would be too big for this post. Sorry if i am being unprofessional!
